# Number of Candles at Lighting

Tags: number, shabbat, candle-lighting

How many candles should one light on Erev Shabbos and Yom Tov? And why that number?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13415/the-custom-of-adding-a-candle-for-each-child

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57126

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of lighting is to prepare for *shabas* in a respectable way and provide visibility during the night. The former is a fulfillment of the rabbinic requirement to "honor" *shabas*, and the latter is a fulfillment of the rabbinic requirement to "enjoy" *shabas*. Notably for both of these considerations, the *Ramba"m* states that the requirement is "that a candle is lit", since it depends so much on the external functionality of the light (for attractiveness and visibility) and not the act of lighting.

Only one flame is required, but it is a very widespread custom to light two - one for each of the positive Biblical commandments "זכור את יום השבת" (mention the sabbath day) and "שמור את יום השבת" (keep the sabbath day).

Comment: Can you cite that this is the reasoning behind the widespread custom? Doing so would improve this answer.

Answer (score 5):

To supplement, not supplant, [WAF's good answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7607), which indicated that the reason for two candles is that they correspond to "זכור" and "שמור", I'll note that on holidays two are lit also, corresponding to man and woman. (I don't pretend to understand this correspondence, but that's what *Taame Haminhagim* 260 says, citing the *Eliyahu Raba*. He (*TH*, in the *kuntres acharon* 14, q.v.) further cites the *B'ne Yisaschar* as saying "I've heard from those who are careful that one should light thirty-six lights for *Shabas*" and giving a reason.)

Answer (score 4):

My family's custom is that a married woman lights two plus one for each of her kids when at home but only two when away; a man or single, childless woman who lights lights but two. I have no source and don't know the reason.

Comment: What about a single child-full woman?

Comment: @DoubleAA, dunno.

Comment: A nice reason for this is provided by Rabbi Yisroel Chaim Friedman of Rachov זצ"ל in hisלקוטי מהרי"ח, חלק ב' סדר התנהגות ע"ש, עמוד 26 where he writes that in מסכת שבת כג: it states that those who light many candles merit to have sons and sons-in-laws that are תורה scholars. Therefore, each time that they gave birth to a son or daughter they would add a candle, as in so doing,  "יזכו לבנין וחתנין תלמידי חכמים"– “They will merit sons and sons-in-law that are Torah scholars”.

Answer (score 2):

first of all meicar hadin you need only one.
in any case most people light 2 because of shamor and zachor. including many single bahurim. when married there's also the logic of one candle per person in the household, so a young couple 2 and then 1 more for each child.
but you go only up not down in kedusha, meaning you only add candles but don't retract, after a child gets married for example the mother keeps lighting the same number of candles.

I met a lady once that added some candles more after the iom kipur war, she made some kind of deal with H' itbarach that if her husband got back from the war she would add on the shabat candles.

also some people add a candle if they forget to light (as opposed to not being able to for some reason)

Answer (score 1):

Mahloket Aharonim as to what the Ari used to do. Baer HaTev says 7 Al Pi HaAri (Orah Haim 263), and I believe the Rashash says 2. The accepted opinion is 2.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason to light two.

The numerical value of the Hebrew word for candle ("Ner") is 250. The Ramah, in [Darcei Moshe 271:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14265&pgnum=455), brings in the name of the Maharil that one should look at the candles during Kidush as a healing for the loss of eyesight caused by taking big steps. The Talmud ([Shabbat 113B](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=113b&format=pdf)) says that every big step one takes removes 1/500th of the brightness of a man's eyes.

2 times "Ner" is 500, and looking at the candles restores the eyesight.

Answer (score 1):

my great grandmother had a minhag that she would light depending on how many aliyos there were. e.g. on shabbos that would be 7 and on Yom Kippur, I think there would be 5. no clue as for a source or reason but she was from Hungary so it's probably some Hungarian minhag.