# Why 2 shabbos candles?

Tags: shabbat, number, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, candle-lighting

Why do women light two candles, specifically, for Shabbos? Is it one for the husband and one for the wife? Is it one for *shamor* and one for *zochor*?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7605/number-of-candles-at-lighting/7607#7607

Comment: How do you know they do?

Comment: I clarified the question to match what I think you're trying to ask. If you want to ask another question about the suitability of a specific pair of candlesticks, please post it separately, since it's a completely different issue than that of the first question. If you do, please make sure to include details about why you are interested in the suitability of that pair, in particular.

Comment: The minhags for number of candles differ considerably. A lot of single women light 2 for shamor and zochor. Chabad (maybe others) light 1 until they are married, then light extras for husband and kids, as well as any weeks in the past that were missed. Many mainstream yeshivish single women light 0 if someone else in the home is lighting (that is, one person lights the candles per dwelling).