# Why 2 candles for yom tov

Tags: minhag, shabbat, number, yom-tov, candle-lighting

For Shabos, there is a custom to light 2 candles: one for shamor and one for zachor.

Shulchan aruch harav 263.1:

> ‏…אחד כנגד זכור ואחד כנגד שמור…‏

I understand that on yomtov they (the people that light on shabos) also light 2 candles.

Why?

Source?

Comment: At least derabanan, YT also has a Shamor type component and a Zachor type component

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7605

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Pri Migadim](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3135) says this is the custom, and suggests it is for man and woman, pointing to [Eliya Rabba](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1747), who explains what that means: A man has 248 limbs, a woman 252. נר (candle) is 250, so 250 times 2 equals the number of limbs in man and woman combined. The Eliya Rabba brings this as an alternative reason for two candles on Shabbos. There the Eliya Rabba also suggests another reason for two candles - for the two souls which are combined together into the body of a person.

Comment: In primegadim it is in, orach haim 514 mishbitais zahav 12 by the end

Comment: Eliya rabba is 263.2

Comment: What two souls?

Comment: @DoubleAA, The Eliya Rabbah doesn't elaborate.